# How can I make this query run more efficiently in MongoDB?

Tags: .net, vb.net, mongodb, database

What I'm basically doing is counting how many time a url has been viewed, and whenever some user on a channel ID views some kind of url I first Select the document that matches this url and this channel ID,

- If not exist, create it and set it's count to 1, create a date to specify the time of generation and  set its TTL to 86400 (basically it means that this document will be deleted in one day).
- If exists, increment its count field and save.

Now I'm seeing some performance issues, and I heard that update operations on MongoDB can create high impact on it, how can I implement it in such way that it won't be so heavy on the db?

This is the code I'm using:

```
  Dim client = New MongoClient(MongoHelper.mongoRedirectConnectionString) 
        Dim domain As String = MerDecisionTaker.FixAddress(url)
        mongo = client.GetServer()
        db = mongo.GetDatabase("urls_check")
        table = db.GetCollection("urls_check")
        searchQuery = Builders.Query.And(Builders.Query.EQ("url", url), Builders.Query.EQ("channel", channel))
        tableNew = db.GetCollection("ForbiddenURLS")
        Dim forbiddenDocumentRedirect = tableNew.FindOneAs(Of MongoLiveNotifiedDocumentClass)(searchQuery)
        If (forbiddenDocumentRedirect Is Nothing) Then
            relevantObj = table.FindOneAs(Of MongoLiveNotifiedDocumentClass)(searchQuery)
            If (relevantObj Is Nothing) Then

                Dim settingsTable As MongoCollection = db.GetCollection("urls_checkSettings")

                Dim channelSettings = settingsTable.FindOneAs(Of channelSettings)(Builders.Query.EQ("channel", channel))
                If channelSettings Is Nothing Then
                    channelSettings = settingsTable.FindOneAs(Of channelSettings)(Builders.Query.EQ("channel", "channel"))
                End If
                If channelSettings IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim newDoc As MongoLiveNotifiedDocumentClass = New MongoLiveNotifiedDocumentClass()
                    newDoc.date_created = DateTime.Now
                    newDoc.channel = channel
                    newDoc.url = url
                    newDoc.maxCount = channelSettings.maxCount
                    newDoc.Count = 1

                    If (url IsNot Nothing) Then

                        table.Insert(Of MongoLiveNotifiedDocumentClass)(newDoc)
                    End If
                End If

            Else
                If relevantObj.Count >= relevantObj.maxCount Then
                    Dim newDoc As MongoForbiddenURLDocumentClass = New MongoForbiddenURLDocumentClass()
                    newDoc.url = url
                    newDoc.channel = channel
                    tableNew.Update(searchQuery, Builders.Update.Replace(newDoc), MongoDB.Driver.UpdateFlags.Upsert)
                Else
                    relevantObj.Count += 1
                    table.Save(relevantObj)
                End If

            End If

        End If
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you describe the performance problems better? Can you post an explain for the query or queries that are too slow? What indexes do you have on the collection?